# Query sorts on date not time

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-blade

So I've made a website to reserve a tennis court based on what date you give in the DateTime input (HTML). This works and all, but for instance, you are not allowed to see a court that's not available until the date it's free. So if a court is free on `NOV 30 2021 12:00`, you cant see it if you type `11/30/2021 11:00`. But that doesn't work. It only works by day, so if I fill in `11/29/2021 12:00`, It does work because the court is not free on that day. So how do I make it work, so it also looks at the time?

**Form**

```
<form method="GET" action="/reserveren/date">
    <h4>Selecteer een datum</h4>
    <input type="datetime-local" name="date" 
           class="form-control-lg inputDate">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Volgende 
        <i class="bi bi-arrow-right"></i>
    </button>
</form>
```

**ReserveController**

```
public function getLaneByDate(Request $request)
{
    $date = $request->date;
    $tournaments = Tournament::all()->where('end_date', '<=', $date);

    return view('/reserve-date', compact('tournaments'));
}
```

**Model**

```
class Tournament extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'tournaments';
}
```

My blade page looks like this when all the data is collected:

```
@foreach ($tournaments as $tournament)
    <div class="member">
        <div class="member-img">
            <img src="assets/img/banen/tennisbaan1.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="member-info">
            <h4>{{$tournament->title}}</h4>
            <span>{{$tournament->lane}}</span>
            <p>{{$tournament->description}}</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                    data-bs-target="#confirmModal">Reserveer
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: You haven't shown us your model ... but see if any of the responses in this thread help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32832625/421195

Comment: Have you confirmed that the value you're getting back from the form is something your database understands, before jamming it into a query?

Comment: Good question, because the data in the URL looks like this '2021-12-01T11%3A40' . So this is maybe a reason why it doesn't sort on times. Is there a way to format this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Carbon unexpected date-time format in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46528154/carbon-unexpected-date-time-format-in-laravel)

Comment: So "the data in the URL" is `'2021-12-01T11:40'` (ASCII 0x3a == ":").  Q: Could you please provide more information about $tournaments?  Is it a Laravel "Eloquent" model?  Is it being read from the DB, or from a URL?  I'm interested in seeing if there's a way we can remove  "time" (leaving "date only") at the *MODEL* level, *BEFORE* invoking ".all()".

Comment: Also note that your code `Tournament::all()->where(...)` is pulling every record from the database and then filtering it in PHP. Instead you should do the filtering on the database and only fetch the records you need. `Tournament::where(...)->get()`.

Comment: $tournaments is indeed a Laravel Eloquent model. it's being read by the database i'm working with too. @paulsm4

Comment: @miken32 I've removed the All() function and replaced it with an whereDate function with at the end a get(). But this basically does the same stuff for me, it still wont look at the time I'm giving, only the date. And yes the format is indeed right (Y-m-d hh:mm)

Comment: Okay, sooo I don't know what I've changed but it seems to work now, its sorts by date and the time i give it. Thanks again for all the help btw, really much appreciated

Comment: If `%3A` is in the database table, then it sounds like someone used `urlencode()` unnecessarily.  Still, if `2021-12-01T11%3A40` is treated as a string, it will correctly sort.  Try to trace the data as it is acquired, stored, reloaded, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A `<datetime-local>` element [always returns a value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local) with `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm` format. You can create a Carbon object from the request value and pass that to the `where()` method instead of the raw string.

Note I've changed your code to filter records at the database level, rather than pulling everything from the database and sorting it with PHP. This is far more efficient, once you get a reasonable number of records in your database. I've made the date check [conditional](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses), so if there is no date it will still return all records.

```php
public function getLaneByDate(Request $request)
{
    $tournaments = Tournament::query()
        ->when($request->filled('date'), function ($q) use ($request) {
            $q->where('end_date', '<=', Carbon::create($request->date));
        })
        ->get();

    return view('/reserve-date', compact('tournaments'));
}
```

This assumes your validation code is making sure `$request->date` is either empty or a valid date.

Comment: Thanks for the help btw bud. But when I try to use your code i get some syntaxing errors. I'm sorry if the problem is obvious, I'm very new to Laravel

Comment: You are probably using an obsolete version of PHP. I will edit for end-of-life versions. You should upgrade ASAP.

Comment: @BigBongo: 1) Please do check your PHP, Laravel and Apache versions, and consider updating if necessary/if practical.  2) Please update your post, and copy/paste the code that's now "working".  3) Please "upvote" and "accept" miken32's reply if you found it helpful.